# Omitting the hypotheses of finiteness of the measure in Egorov theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

I want to prove that if I omit the fact that $\mu (X) < \infty$ in Egorov theorem and place instead that our functions $|f_n| <g$ and $g$ is integrable, we still get the result of Egorov's theorem.

Fix $m$ a natural number.

I took $ w_{n} = |f_n-f|$ and thus by DCT $\int |f_{n} - f|$ goes to zero.

Then I took $\bigcup_n {( w_{n} \geq 1/m)}$. I need its measure to be finite. Its measure is less than the sum of the measures of each $ w_n\geq 1/m)$ varying $n$, and by Tchebychev, this is less than $m\int|f_{n} - f|$.  But I got stuck here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can, without loss of generality, assume that the sequence $f_n$ is decreasing and convergent almost everywhere to $0$ (if it's not the case, consider $\displaystyle g_n(x):=\sup_{k\geq n}|f_k(x)-f(x)|$, which is dominated by $2g$, an integrable function. We fix $\varepsilon>0$, and we are looking for a measurable set $A$ such that $\mu(X\setminus A)\leq \varepsilon$ and the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$.
We have for all integers $j$ and $n$ that
$$\mu\left(\left\{g_n\geq \frac 1j\right\}\right)\leq j\int_X |g_n|d\mu,$$
and the monotone convergence theorem gives us that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X |g_n|d\mu=0$. Hence for all $j\geq 1$, we can pick $n_j\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$\mu\left(\left\{g_{n_j}\geq \frac 1j\right\}\right)\leq \varepsilon2^{-j}.$$
Now, put $A_j:=\left\{g_{n_j}\geq \frac 1j\right\}$ and $\displaystyle A:=\bigcap_{j\geq 1}\complement_X A_j$. We have
$$\mu(X\setminus A)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{j\geq 1}A_j\right)\leq \sum_{j\geq 1}\mu(A_j)=\varepsilon\left(\frac 1{1-2^{-1}}-1\right)=\varepsilon$$
and $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in A}\,|g_{n_j}-0|\leq \frac 1j$. Since the sequence $\displaystyle\left\{\sup_{x\in A}\,g_n(x)\right\}$ is decreasing and has a sub-sequence which converges to $0$, the whole sequence converges to $0$, and we are done.

Comment: What does $\complement_X$ mean?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan The complement in $X$.

Comment: The complement of $A$ in $X$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{} $

Comment: can u  drop the hyotheis of measrability. gicen epislon we jwe just want aset A outside which te covergence is uniform or atleat one n for which the covergencce holds for allx and A should have outer measure less than epsilon. the lemma in rudin works with upward continuit of outer measure to get the complement of A but as outer measure is not additive one does not get measure less than epsilon we can keep g integrable.

Comment: the comment of mine addes above is relevantas if we can do this usinga theorem in henstock kurzweil intgration may be of banach valued functions may be banach valued premeasure also without using basolute continuity we can get DCT. g will be positive dominating function integrable with positive subadditive measure. if u contact  me anilped@hotmail.com full credit will be given and we will get a result,

Comment: actually i have one dct where no measurabiliry is used but there cTHE SEQUENCE IS CAUCHY IN MEASURE

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.

Define the sets $G_m := \{x: g(x)>1/m\}$. Since $\int g <\infty$, we have $\mu(G_m)<\infty$ for all $m$. For each $m$, apply Egoroff's Theorem to find a $E_m\subseteq G_m$ such that $\mu(E_m)=\epsilon/2^m$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $G_m-E_m$.

**Claim:** Let $E=\cup_{m=1}^{\infty}E_m$ and we note that $\mu(E)\le \epsilon$. I claim that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $X-E$.

Indeed, it suffices to show that for every given $k$, there exists $N$ such that $|f_n-f| < 2/k$ on $X-E$ for all $n\ge N$.

- On $X-G_k$, we have $|f_n|,|f|\le g \le 1/k$ so $|f_n-f| < 2/k$ holds for every $n$.
- On $G_k - E$, which is a subset of $G_k - E_k$, we have that $f_n \to f$ uniformly, so we simply pick $N$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

We can write:

$$X=\{ g>1\}\cup(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\{ 2^{-k}<g\leqslant2^{1-k}\right\})\cup \{g=0\}$$
Notice that the above sets are all disjoint.

Apply Egoroff's theorem to each of the sets:
$$\{ g>1\},\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\{ 2^{-k}<g\leqslant2^{1-k}\right\}$$

Then there exist $A\subset G=\{g>1\}$ ,and  $A_k\subset G_k=\left\{ 2^{-k}<g\leqslant2^{1-k}\right\}, $ such that:
$$\mu (A)<\varepsilon/2 ,   \mu (A_k)<\varepsilon 4^{-k}  $$ and $$f_n\longrightarrow f$$uniformly in $E^c=(G\setminus A)\cup(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k\setminus A_k)\cup \{f_n=0,\forall n\}$, where the last set in the union is a superset of $\{g=0\}$.

Now, it suffices to prove that $\mu (E)<\varepsilon$.

Indeed, after some simple set calculations (using the fact that we decomposed X in disjoint sets) we can obtain that:
$$E=X\setminus\left\{(G\setminus A)\cup(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k\setminus A_k)\cup \{f_n=0,\forall n\}\right\}\subset$$ $$(X\setminus(G\setminus A))\cap(X\setminus(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}G_k\setminus A_k))\cap (X\setminus\{g=0\})\subset$$
$$A\cup(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k)$$
Therefore, $$\mu (E)\leqslant \mu (A\cup(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k))\leqslant \mu(A)+\mu (\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k))<\varepsilon/2+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \varepsilon4^{-k} =\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/3 <\varepsilon$$

Comment: Can you explain the last subset relation? I have no idea how it follows.