# Egorov's Theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $g,f,f_n:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of functions that have the following property:

i) $f_n \to f$ a.e

ii)$|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ a.e and $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Show that for each given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an closed subset $F_\varepsilon$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|\mathbb{R}^n-F_\varepsilon|< \varepsilon$, and $f_n$ converges uniformely on $F_\varepsilon$ to $f$, where $|\cdot|$ means the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thanks for help!

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: Because it was a question in my exame some hours ago.

Comment: Have you proved this result for $n=1$? If you had, then modulo this fact the proof is easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under these assumptions, there is $S_\varepsilon$ such that $\lambda(\mathbb R^n\setminus S_\varepsilon)\lt\varepsilon$ and $\sup_{x\in S_\varepsilon}|f_n-f|\to 0$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83424/omitting-the-hypotheses-of-finiteness-of-the-measure-in-egorov-theorem).

But this $S_\varepsilon$ has no reason to be closed. However, by an approximation argument, we can find $F_\varepsilon\subset S_\varepsilon$ closed such that $\lambda(S_\varepsilon\setminus F_\varepsilon)\lt \varepsilon$·