# Usefulness of alternative version of Egoroff's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

I was looking at this different version of Egoroff's Theorem:
[Omitting the hypotheses of finiteness of the measure in Egorov theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83424/omitting-the-hypotheses-of-finiteness-of-the-measure-in-egorov-theorem).

I'm wondering if someone can show me an example where you can use this result instead of the standard one.

In particular, I'm looking for a sequence of measurable (complex-valued) functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $X$ , $\mu (X) = \infty$ ,  such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. and $|f_n| <g \quad ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $g$ is integrable.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The condition "$|f_n|<g$ where $g$ is integrable" wouldn't be easier to verify than $\mu(X)<\infty$ in cases where $\mu(X)<\infty$ is false, and, thus, infinitely hard to verify.

Comment: @jwhite Think you mean 'The condition "..." wouldn't be more difficult to verify...'.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It *would* be easier (or at least as easy) to verify as something impossible to verify.

Comment: I've just updated the question! Hope this helps.

Comment: Any Example where one uses the dominated convergence will work. $f_n(x)=(1-x/n)^n \,\cos(x/n)\,\mathbb{1}_{[0,n]}(x)$